# ¿Cómo cambiar múltiples columnas numéricas a formato fecha?

Tags: r

Quisiera saber como cambiar toda una fila, desde la columna 3 a la 3703 a formato fecha ya que aparecen como `43922,43921,43920,...,40268`

Intente con `As.date(df$columna, format=="%d%m%Y")` y no funcionó

Comment: Bienvenida Valeria Arango a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 0):

Que en una columna dónde esperas una fecha haya un número, eso es señal que tienes un problema anterior al de "como convertir un número en una fecha", deberías atacar esto más bien. De cualquier manera, puedes convertir cualquier número en un valor de fecha, siempre que definas el `origin` que es la fecha de inicio, te explico, las fechas se pueden trabajar como la cantidad de días desde una fecha determinada, por convención R  usa el primero de enero de 1970. Si este es tu caso, podrías hacer:

```
as.Date(c(43922,43921,43920), origin='1970-01-01')
[1] "2090-04-03" "2090-04-02" "2090-04-01"
```

Me da la impresión por las fechas resultantes, que se trata de una importación desde Excel, éste trata las fechas con un origen a `1900-01-01`, pero no es tan simple, por:

- El origen en Excel es el índice 1, en R El origen es el índice 0
- Hay un [bug histórico](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/wrongly-assumes-1900-is-leap-year) en Excel que considera válida la fecha `1900-02-29`

Por lo que en realidad, nuestro origen será dos días menos:

```
as.Date(c(43922,43921,43920), origin='1899-12-30')
[1] "2020-04-01" "2020-03-31" "2020-03-30"
```

De cualquier manera, vuelvo a repetirte, tu problema parece ser la importación, leyendo adecuadamente cualquier Excel, las fechas deberían ser fechas.

Por otro lado planteas la necesidad de convertir múltiples columnas a la vez. Podrías hacerlo así:

```
data.frame(lapply(df[, 3:3703], function(x) as.Date(x, format="%Y-%m-%d", origin="1899-12-30")))
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51618720/6836377